# Php and javascript submiting form with changing form name?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hi there i am working on one php java submithing comment system and now i have a problem which i can not solve alone.
I just want to ask how i can make this

```
$('#addCommentForm'+x).submit(function(e){

DO something here
}
```

addCommentForm has many numbers after it like this: addCommentForm1 addCommentForm2 addCommentForm3 addCommentForm4 and rising. So how i can make this dinamicly changing name to work submithing in java ?

```
var x = $_POST['comentonpost'];
```

The $_POST is coming from here:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> var $_POST = <?php echo !empty($_POST)?json_encode($_POST):'null';?>; </script>
```

X - is post value that i am getting from HTML form for submiting the info but if i press once submit on one comment the javascript is working only for this comment until the page is refreshed.
Here you can see --- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okqQsPCZqVE

Here is the whole java script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var x = $_POST['comentonpost'];
/* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

/* This flag will prevent multiple comment submits: */
var working = false;

/* Listening for the submit event of the form: */
$('#addCommentForm'+x).submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    if(working) return false;

    working = true;
    $('#submit').val('Working..');
    $('span.error').remove();

    /* Sending the form fileds to submit.php: */
    $.post('comment.submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

        working = false;
        $('#submit').val('Submit');


            /* 
            /   If the insert was successful, add the comment
            /   below the last one on the page with a slideDown effect
            /*/

            $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer'+x).slideDown();


    },'json');

});

});
```

So please tell me how can i fix that and make this script working well without refreshing the page?

Comment: This code is not Java, it's Javascript. Despite the similarity of the names, it's not the same language.

Comment: Also, you're mixing Javascript and PHP (`$_POST`) all together. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Maybe this make sense:
<script type='text/javascript'> var $_POST = <?php echo !empty($_POST)?json_encode($_POST):'null';?>; </script>

Comment: Hum, ok... I find this very ambigous but I guess this should work.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `var x = $_POST['comentonpost']` with this:

```
var x = <?= !empty($_POST['comentonpost']) ? json_encode($_POST['comentonpost']) : 'null';?>;
```

Javascript arrays must be defined first by using `var variableName = new Array();`, otherwise they will function as if they are standard variables. So it is best to avoid the hassle of setting and handling them if they are not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Danny, but it's not working. I've tried what you've said and again it's only working with only one HTML submit FORM. I've changed it in the javascript but something i do not make right. Need help please. When i try to press the submit button on other comment it's refreshing the page. Here you can see what i am talking about - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okqQsPCZqVE